# data binding aria label not working on button tag

Tags: knockout.js, wai-aria

I have this button that i want to add an `aria-label` to but i want to bind it so that i don't have hard coded text in my file so i tried to data-bind it but i am not getting the aria-label to show properly.

This is what works and is read by the screen reader:

```
<button class="styling" aria-label="Some random text">
     <span class="icon"></span>
</button>
```

but this is what i would like to work but it is not showing an aria-label with appropriate text:

```
<button class="styling" data-bind="attr:{'aria-label': textFromModal}">
     <span class="icon"></span>
</button>
```

UPDATE:

Here is the modal i have - i know that it is working because i am displaying other items from it and they are displaying fine.

```
DisplayViewModal = function(){
    var self;
    self = {
            ....
            textFromModal: 'Label text to show',
            ....
           };
    return self;
}
return DisplayViewModal;
```

Comment: show the binded viewmodel.

Comment: let us see the viewmodel, the "textFromModal" might be blank that's why the aria-label is not showing.

Comment: Check out the Knockoutjs Context debugger - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/knockoutjs-context-debugg/oddcpmchholgcjgjdnfjmildmlielhof?hl=en - It should be able to give you clue if the textFromModel has a value.

Comment: @EricBronnimann whenever i tried using the debugger either i am not using it the right way or something. How would i be able to check the value with the debugger?

Comment: @JoelRamosMichaliszen i went ahead and updated with what i have for the viewmodel.

Comment: I posted a small sample with the Knockout debugger in action here: https://github.com/erbronni/knockout-context-debug  One thing to look for is any errors in the bindings, since an exception in one binding might throw off the parsing of subsequent bindings.  One way to do this is to remove all the bindings and then methodically add them back in, testing each binding to ensure it is working.  It is tedious, but sometimes it is the only way to find out what is causing the problem.

Comment: @EricBronnimann Thanks or the example and looking into my console when i run the page - i am not getting any errors but i am also not seeing the label text that i am expecting. I just see this: `data-bind="attr:{'aria-label':locale.playbackSpeed}"` Not sure what this means since i am not getting errors

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be working (for me, in FF). Although I don't have access to a screen reader, it behaves as expected with the screen reader wand.

1. Enable the wand
2. Hover over the button.
3. See the expected text.
4. Confirm DOM shows the area-label. I also see this in IE11.

Are you using a screen reader? Maybe disable it to confirm you see the data being bound. Then enable it and see that it's not being bound.

[image]

Comment: Are you using some kind of addon for this black menu? Where can I get the "screen reader wand" ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and it turns out, that it was not shown when `textFromModal` didn't have a value. When I set it, it started to work. My exact HTML looks like this:

```
<textarea
    aria-controls="chat-history"
    class="chat-input-textbox"
    data-bind="attr: {'aria-label': textFromModal}">
</textarea>
```

I checked with a `<button>` and works the same way.